# Permanently change default language and keyboard settings - what am I missing?

Tags: debian, keyboard-layout, language, keymap, locale

I'm trying to configure a Debian Linux (ARMHF 3.8.13-bone20) on a BeagleBone Black to use German as the default language and keyboard layout, which does not work, and I can't see why. I'm talking about the console settings, not X or Gnome etc.  Here are my settings and what I did so far:

```
dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

Here I chose `de_DE.UTF-8 UTF-8` and unselected `en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8`.

Output from `locale`:

```
LANG=de_DE.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Content of `/etc/default/locale`:

```
LANG=de_DE.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=de_DE.UTF-8
```

Content of `/etc/default/keyboard`:

```
# KEYBOARD CONFIGURATION FILE
# Consult the keyboard(5) manual page.
XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBLAYOUT="de"
XKBVARIANT="nodeadkeys"
XKBOPTIONS="terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp"
BACKSPACE="guess"
```

I ran `setupcon` after making these settings and it didn't change anything, the layout still was `en_US`.

After that, I ran

```
dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

and set `German - no dead keys` as keyboard layout. Still no change, neither at once nor after a reboot.

Next, I tried

```
dpkg-reconfigure console-data
```

Here I chose

```
Choose layout from entire list
```

and then

```
pc / quertz / German / Standard / latin1 - no dead keys
```

The output after that was:

```
Looking for keymap to install:
de-latin1-nodeadkeys
#
```

At this moment, the correct keyboard layout is present, but unfortunately things revert to the English (US) keyboard layout after reboot.

What can I do to permanently change the keyboard layout? As far as I can see the correct keymap must be present as it can get loaded, but only until the next reboot. What am I missing here?

Update: When connecting via SSH the German keymap gets loaded.

Comment: Hi, I've exact the same issues with my gnome installation. Are there some new information?

Comment: This question is from 2 years and 9 months ago and it is still happening to me in July 2017.  Has anyone actually solved this?  It is annoying that I keep getting set back to the gb keyboard.  Not that big a deal since for me that means the " and @ get reversed.  I can live with that.  Going in through the GUI fixes it until the next (very rare) power recycle as I back up the SD card.  I echo the clue in the update:  This only happens to the one RPi where I have a keyboard and monitor.  It never happens when I use RDP.  I don't see an accepted answer so I guess we're left to just deal with it.

Comment: 2020 and getting this only now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The combination of commands that worked for me were:

```
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
$ setupcon
$ sudo update-initramfs -u
```

And then reboot.

The last command rebuilds your GRUB boot settings. I don't know for sure if the keyboard layout is set in the boot image, but I noticed that the prompt for the full-disk encryption passphrase uses my system keyboard layout setting. At the point that prompt appears the keyboard settings couldn't be loaded from /etc because the root partition hasn't been decrypted yet. That led me to believe that there is probably a setting written into the boot partition, thus the motivation to run `update-initramfs`.

Comment: Ah, the `update-initramfs -u` finally made it stick after reboot!

Answer (score 16):

You might try to add the boot parameters of `debian-installer/keymap=de` and `keymap=de`.

Also, the answer at the thread [Keyboard layout HELP](http://www.turnkeylinux.org/forum/support/20130912/keyboard-layout-help) says :

> 1. Go to the webmin and do this SYSTEM -> SOFTWARE PACKADGES -> UPGRADE ALL
> 2. (I don't recall if the order was this) Go to the console and do the following:
>
>    apt-get install console-data
>      apt-get install console-setup
>      apt-get install console-locales
>      apt-get install keyboard-configuration
> 3. Do the dpkg-reconfigure for each of the packets above. REBOOT.

So maybe your problem is that you haven't done all of them before rebooting.

Comment: This didn't work for me (on Ubuntu 12.04), I have to run `dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` after every reboot.

Comment: On Raspbian I just had to install console-data and then selected pc/quertz/German/Standard/latin1 and everything works.

Comment: does not work for me (debian stretch 9.1.0).

Comment: You misspelled "packages".

Comment: @IkemKrueger: This is in the original quote, 8 years ago.

Comment: Got the issue and find this post but there is still no solution :/ This does **not** work.

Answer (score 16):

After `dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration`, you need to run

```
setupcon
```

> ```
> NAME
>        setupcon - sets up the font and the keyboard on the console
>
> SYNOPSIS
>        setupcon [OPTION]... [VARIANT]
>
> DESCRIPTION
>        setupcon  is a program for fast and easy setup of the font and the key‐
>        board on the console.  Most of the time  you  invoke  setupcon  without
>        arguments.   The  keyboard configuration is specified in ~/.keyboard or
>        /etc/default/keyboard.  The font configuration is specified in  ~/.con‐
>        sole-setup or /etc/default/console-setup.  Consult keyboard(5) and con‐
>        sole-setup(5) for instructions how to configure these two files.
> ```

Comment: Should be the accepted answer, simple and effective.

Comment: does not work for me (debian stretch 9.1.0).

Comment: Works on Debian 9.13

Comment: use sudo may help - it doesn't give an error if it is required

Answer (score 9):

On Stretch you'll need console-setup (in addition to keyboard-configuration), which includes the necessary systemd-service keyboard-setup:

```
apt-get install keyboard-configuration console-setup
```

Comment: I think this one is the most general/useful answer... `console-setup` is the key

Answer (score 2):

```
dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
udevadm trigger --subsystem-match=input --action=change
```

Comment: While these commands look like they might achieve *something* that the asker wants, it would be good to add a brief description of *why* they would do so.

Comment: does not work for me (debian stretch 9.1.0).

Comment: This doesnt work long term if it's not already working. the udevadm just triggers the config change without a reboot.

Answer (score 2):

The solution for me was to comment out all the locale relevant variables at `/etc/profile`

```
#export LANG="de_DE.utf8"
#export LANGUAGE="de_DE.utf8"
#export LC_ALL="de_DE.utf8"
```

(I wanted to get rid off the German :))

and then set my locale as I wish within `/etc/default/locale`

The debian wiki page https://wiki.debian.org/Locale was the most helpfull document I found.

Comment: locale and keyboard layout are not one of the same.

Answer (score 1):

To change the german keyboard in Kali Linux 2020.02 (Debian) do the following:

1. `dpkg-reconfigure locales`

   Choose `de_DE.UTF-8 UTF-8` and unselect `en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8` (by pressing <kbd>Space</kbd>)
2. `dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration`

   Choose your keyboard hardware
3. For Kali Linux 2020.2 (Debian) goto GUI

   *Settings*/*Settings Editor*

   To Channel *Keyboard-layout*

   Under Line *XkbLayout String* change the value to `de` (delete `us`)

This permanently changes the layout to the german keyboard.